# Combining neighbor polygons (NOT touching) making one using JTS/GeoTools?

Tags: geotools, jts-topology-suite

This question is similar to:

- [Combining touching polygons, keeping all attributes from Class "A" feature, using ArcGIS Desktop?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/173417/combine-touching-polygons-keeping-all-attributes-from-class-a-feature) and
- [Combining adjacent polygons sharing similar trait into single polygon using ArcGIS Desktop?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/23365/how-to-combine-adjacent-polygons-sharing-similar-trait-into-single-polygon?rq=1)

but need to do this programmatically with JTS.

This question is not for **overlapping polygons** or touching polygons but for **adjacent polygons** that is the difference when they don't touch but next to each other.
the answer to this question [Remove intersect/touch from polygons, to making one with JTS/GeoTools](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/268531/remove-intersect-touch-from-polygons-to-making-one-with-jts-geotools) , worked for intersecting..but not for adjacent.

I am trying to  implement this using JTS/GeoTools.. i found the .dissolve(..) thinking that would do the trick but it is not working.

The original GeoJson( `//loadAdjacentGeoJson()` )

[image]
https://gist.github.com/boundaries-io/ef7c423f3e174de0f185cb86a1e873e3

***Updated Solution***:

```
 for (GeoJsonPolygon geoJsonPolygon : geoJsonPolygonList) {
                Coordinate[] coordinates = toCoordinateArray(geoJsonPolygon);
                SimpleFeatureBuilder simpleFeatureBuilder = new SimpleFeatureBuilder(simpleFeatureType);
                simpleFeatureBuilder.add(inflate(geometryFactory.createPolygon(coordinates)));  //add inflated polygons

                SimpleFeature simpleFeature = simpleFeatureBuilder.buildFeature(Integer.toString(index));
                simpleFeature.getUserData().put("zipcode", postal.getZipCode());
                index = index + 1;
                geometryList.add((Geometry)simpleFeature.getDefaultGeometry());
            }

        Object obj = geometryFactory.buildGeometry(geometryList);

        GeometryCollection geometryCollection = (GeometryCollection) obj;

        Geometry union = geometryCollection.union();  //perform union

        LOGGER.info(new GeoJsonWriter().write(geometryCollection)); //shows inflated polygons with overlap

        LOGGER.info(new GeoJsonWriter().write( deflate( union ))); //deflate back.
```

inflated polygons so union will work.:
[image]
https://gist.github.com/boundaries-io/80614499880bb4dabb57205cc529ca7c

inlate/deflate methods:

```
private Geometry deflate(Geometry geom) {
        BufferParameters bufferParameters = new BufferParameters();
        bufferParameters.setEndCapStyle(BufferParameters.CAP_ROUND);
        bufferParameters.setJoinStyle(BufferParameters.JOIN_MITRE);
        Geometry buffered = BufferOp.bufferOp(geom,-.0001, bufferParameters);
        buffered.setUserData(geom.getUserData());
        return buffered;
    }

    private Geometry inflate(Geometry geom) {
        BufferParameters bufferParameters = new BufferParameters();
        bufferParameters.setEndCapStyle(BufferParameters.CAP_ROUND);
        bufferParameters.setJoinStyle(BufferParameters.JOIN_MITRE);
        Geometry buffered = BufferOp.bufferOp(geom,.0001, bufferParameters);
        buffered.setUserData(geom.getUserData());
        return buffered;
    }
```

results:
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was able to complete this by using JTS `com.vividsolutions.jts.operation.buffer.BufferOp` 
inflating, then performing a union, then deflating back.

```
private Geometry deflate(Geometry geom) {
        BufferParameters bufferParameters = new BufferParameters();
        bufferParameters.setEndCapStyle(BufferParameters.CAP_ROUND);
        bufferParameters.setJoinStyle(BufferParameters.JOIN_MITRE);
        Geometry buffered = BufferOp.bufferOp(geom, -.0001, bufferParameters);
        buffered.setUserData(geom.getUserData());
        return buffered;
    }

    private Geometry inflate(Geometry geom) {
        BufferParameters bufferParameters = new BufferParameters();
        bufferParameters.setEndCapStyle(BufferParameters.CAP_ROUND);
        bufferParameters.setJoinStyle(BufferParameters.JOIN_MITRE);
        Geometry buffered = BufferOp.bufferOp(geom, .0001, bufferParameters);
        buffered.setUserData(geom.getUserData());
        return buffered;
    }
```